# How come import subprocess.Popen not work and from subprocess import Popen does work? What "type" of object am I allowed to import in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

What is the difference between `from x import y` and `import x.y` ?

How come `from subprocess import Popen` work but not `import subprocess.Popen` ?

Also is there only specific type(s) of objects that python allows to import? Say, you can only import modules in python but not classes or functions within a module?